# Job keep failing when running using a sellf hosted agent. Fails at "Run npm install"

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, npm-install

When trying the run the below job in my AzureDev project, I get the below error message when it gets to the task 'Run npm install' : ##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'npm'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.

[screenshot of yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL3BC.png)

Note: I have added the builtin config, prefix and globalconfig path to system varriable. Although. this was after I had installed/configured agent. so in agent's capabilities, under path, I don't see the path to builtin config, prefix and globalconfig. not sure if that matters. see screenshot. [agent capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlIC8.png)
"builtin" config from C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc
prefix = "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm"
globalconfig = "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc"

I have installed node.js on my machine and also installed npm.

I am simply trying to reproducing steps taught in this ms learning path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-a-build-pipeline/6-create-the-pipeline?pivots=github-codespaces-agent

I have tried adding nmp to agent capability and using the folder path to different npm executable as it's value.
I also added "path: folder path" to the yml file in visual code then commit and push and run but got different error.

The goal is to successfully run the job with my self hosted agent.

Comment: Please, provide the code content of the YML file. Therefore, it can be copied and others can reproduce your code. If possible, format your answer e.g. error message as quotes using this >  and function like that `my_function`

Answer (score 0):

After you have set up the self-hosted agent on the machine, then if you installed the **`npm`** tool and added it to the system environment **`PATH`**, you can re-start either the agent service or the machine. After re-starting, the installed **`npm`** tool can be available for the self-hosted agent and shows on the list of agent capabilities.

Similar behaviors for other tools installed after having set up the self-hosted agent.

---

**EDIT:**

By default, the '**`python`**' command is for **Python2**, and the '**`python3`**' command for **Python3**.

If you want to use the '**`python`**' command for installed **Python3**, you can try below ways to set the Aliases for **Python3**:

- On Windows, try below PowerShell command (also see [here](https://gist.github.com/troyfontaine/e1174ffa2140e7d6f092fe0984225a1d)).

  ```
  Set-Alias python "installation\path\to\python.exe"
  ```
- On Linux (Ubuntu), you can install an extra tool named "[**`python-is-python3`**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/python-is-python3)". This tool updates the Aliases to '**`python`**' for **Python3**.

---

**EDIT2:**

Try the following things on your Windows machine:

1. Uninstall the **Python3** has been manually installed by you.
2. Download and install the latest version of **Node.js** tool.
3. When installing the **Node.js** tool, enable the option "**`Automatically install the necessary tools.`**" on the Setup Wizard. This option will pop-up a terminal window to automatically download, install and configure the new available version of **Python3** and other necessary tools on the machine.
4. You just need to wait for the terminal window to complete the installations of the tools. After that, re-start either the agent service or the machine. Then you can use '**`python`**' command for **Python3** on the machine.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. I have got passed that phase but encountered another issue.

Below is link to the raw log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZjB6YBocFiCtBiN57LgBm82vnvqOh9Mp/view?usp=sharing

Note: I have installed Python and added to system variable and restarted the machine. 
Still in the "Run npm install" task

Comment: @kessy, I have updated my above answer with more suggestions for your new issue. Check and try the suggestions.

Comment: @kessy, Is there any update from you?

Comment: I have I have tried the above without success. I have also followed the recommended link and followed instruction there but output is same.

What I understood from the error logs is it could find python. Although I have it installed and added to environment variable. 

I see similar issue in this trend but couldn't replicate solution as I use windows machine.
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2664

Comment: @kessy, See the new contents I added in my above answer with more suggestions. Chdck and try it.